# Can I use custom serialization like AVRO on specific aerospike SET

Tags: serialization, aerospike

Is it possible to have custom serializer on single aerospike set? I do not want my serializer to be used on other sets in the namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Aerospike allows flex schema. You do not need to define the type of the set or bin upfront. You can encode every bin the way you want. So, whatever data you want to store with AVRO serialization, you can store it as a blob type.